# iMacros javascript nested loops in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, loops, nested, imacros

I have 2 macros I need to run in Firefox.  They both run perfectly as iim's but I need to get them to run together

Macro1: It reads a text file with a number of links on it, loads the link, and moves on to the next

```
var macro1 = "CODE:";
macro1 += "VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro1 += "" + "\n";
macro1 += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\REPORT_LINK_EXT_OBG.TXT" + "\n";
macro1 += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}" + "\n";
macro1 += "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
```

Macro2: Extracts links for each page that macro1 opens.  Problem is, there can be anywhere from 1 to 50 links that macro 2 needs to extract before macro1 moves on again.

```
var macro2 = "CODE:";
macro2 += "VERSION BUILD=7500718 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
macro2 += "SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 2" + "\n";
macro2 += "SET !LOOP 2" + "\n";
macro2 += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n";
macro2 += "TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*WeldDataLog.aspx?* EXTRACT=HREF" + "\n";
macro2 += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:aspnetForm ATTR=ID:ctl00_Main_ucReportHeader_pnlView_txtReportNumber EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
macro2 += "'----------------------------------\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/----Change this" + "\n";
macro2 += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents FILE=LINK_EXT3test.TXT" + "\n";
```

I essentially need

Do
macro1
Do
macro2
Loop
Loop

Can anyone help me get these 2 macros to work with instead of against each other?

Answer (score 1):

```
iimPlay(macro1)

var link1=iimGetLastExtract();

var link2_array=new Array();

for(var i=0; i<50; i++)
{

iimPlay(macro2)
link2_array[i]=iimGetLastExtract();


}
```

Would something like this work for you?

To check if the link is extracted properly you can use this

```
iimPlay(macro)
var link=iimGetLastExtract();

if(link=="EANF")
{

//link is not there

}
else
{

// link is there

}
```

To change position of imacros command.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS={{n}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:someurl.com EXTRACT=HREF";

for (var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{

iimSet("n",i)
iimPlay(macro)

}
```

Comment: So close.  This will navigate to the first report, and extract the first link 50 times.  How do I get it to change href position, and stop when the last link is extracted?  I'll work on tweaking this.  Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use if clause and for example if returned varialbe is equal to #EANF# then you've extracted the last link.  In order to change the position you can use POS={{n}} and before you call the macro it would be iimSet("n",some_number) . I will write this in my post .