# iMacros Loop then Stop then add another command

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

I'm a complete newbie to the world of iMacro scripting, and as such I am having difficulty getting (what I believe to be) a very simply data scrape working.

I would like to know how to loop this thing

```
URL GOTO=link1
URL GOTO=link2
URL GOTO=link3
WAIT SECONDS=7.5
```

Then stop the loop and add another command below

```
URL GOTO=link4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:txt
URL GOTO=link5
```

Instead of doing it like this

```
URL GOTO=link1
URL GOTO=link2
URL GOTO=link3
WAIT SECONDS=7.5
URL GOTO=link1
URL GOTO=link2
URL GOTO=link3
WAIT SECONDS=7.5
URL GOTO=link1
URL GOTO=link2
URL GOTO=link3
WAIT SECONDS=7.5
URL GOTO=link4
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:txt
URL GOTO=link5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not do this with regular imacros iim script in other way than the one you already do - just copy/pasting and creating long script inserting needed code in needed places, you can do this with javascript or similar script which will manage looping logic and run needed code according to stated conditions.

Comment: Then how do you do this using javascript ?

Comment: there are huge amount of imacros JavaScript code examples in SO, here is one of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573127/imacros-javascript-nested-loops-in-firefox?rq=1

Comment: Sadly, i dont understand a thing @@

Comment: Think of JS as wrapping for the iMacros code. When you "wrap" the iMacros code you can do what ever you want in iMacros.